# Loopback : How to get one model data from other mode service method?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, loopbackjs

I'm using loopback angular sdk I'm having two models Tags and Project. I want to get Tags related to that project. I'm having lb-services. I don't know what method to call and how to call it from services. please help. I've tried this code to get tags which is related to project who's id is 1.

```
Project.Tag.find(
    { id: 1 }
);
```

Comment: Can we see some code please. Post what you've tried so far. Really hard to help with such minimal information.

Comment: Now i've attached code.

Comment: Have you reviewed the documentation on setting this up here:
http://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/AngularJS+JavaScript+SDK

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example from a live app ... For a relationship described like so:
https://github.com/ShoppinPal/warehouse/blob/490cbaccfb60922645173a34d53327629b989028/common/models/user-model.json#L28

I can pull the related models on the angular side like so:
https://github.com/ShoppinPal/warehouse/blob/dbf8d1e25592ec9e76d9f6a5f2af6ba6ca74fd9c/client/app/scripts/controllers/login.js#L57

If your problem is purely syntactical then please paste code from model.json file as well so the community can help detect & fix it.